# Postgresql query: update status of limit number of records based on group size

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-update, limit

I have a postgresql table contains a list of email addresses. The table has three columns, Email, EmailServer (e.g., gmail.com, outlook.com, msn.com, and yahoo.com.ca etc.), and Valid (boolean).

Now, I want to group those emails by EmailServer and then update the first 3 records of each large group (count >=6) as Valid = true while leaving the rest of each group as Valid = false.

I failed to get the wanted output by below query:

```
UPDATE public."EmailContacts"   
SET "Valid"=true
WHERE "EmailServer" IN (
    SELECT "EmailServer"
    FROM public."EmailContacts"
    GROUP by "EmailServer"
    HAVING count(*) >=6
    LIMIT 5)
```

Please help to modify so as to get the expected results. Would be greatly appreciated for any kind of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH major_servers AS (
    SELECT email_server
    FROM email_address
    GROUP by email_server
    HAVING count(*) >=6
),
enumerated_emails AS (
    SELECT email,
           email_server,
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY email_server ORDER BY email) AS row_number --TODO:: ORDER BY email - attention
    FROM email_address
    WHERE email_server IN (SELECT email_server FROM major_servers)
)
UPDATE email_address
SET valid = true
WHERE email IN (SELECT email
                FROM enumerated_emails ee
                WHERE ee.row_number <= 3);
```

- The first query `major_servers` finds major groups where more than 5 email servers exist.
- The second query `enumerated_emails` enumerates emails by their **natural order** (*see a TODO comment, I think you should choose another ORDER BY criteria*) which belong to major groups using window function `row_number()`.
- The last query updates the first 3 rows in each major server group.

Find the [sql-fiddle](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yuh2av62) here.

Comment: Works as expected. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the servers, then order the mails from which one and then perform the update. Something like this:

```
WITH DataSourceServers AS 
(
    SELECT "EmailServer"
    FROM public."EmailContacts"
    GROUP by "EmailServer"
    HAVING count(*) >=6
),DataSourceEmails AS
(
    SELECT "Email", row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "EmailServer" ORDER BY "Email") AS rn
    FROM public."EmailContacts"
    WHERE "EmailServer" IN (SELECT "EmailServer" FROM DataSourceServers)
)
UPDATE public."EmailContacts"
SET "Valid" = true
FROM  public."EmailContacts" E
INNER JOIN DataSourceEmails SE
WHERE E."EmailServer" = SE."EmailServer"
    AND E."Email" = SE."Email"
    AND SE.rn <= 3;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the help. Could you please review the last 3 lines? To get it work, I simply modified the last "where" to "ON" and added "EmailServer" to DataSourceEmail. However, the row_number did not play its role as all rows "Valid" became to true now after execution.